# Getting an error when accessing an API to show the open orders

Tags: python

I'm getting the error:

> Type Error: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '**getitem**' on
>   line 12

in this code in Python:

```
import time
import sys, getopt
import datetime
from bittrex import Bittrex
import urllib2, json
import requests

conn = Bittrex('42fcc9eede2b4c5491e540a4a9e9566d','350b094fb57e49e695c8b3a35d994e70')

def main(argv):
    openOrders = conn.get_open_orders
    order1 = openOrders['result']['OrderUuid'][0]
    print order1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

If someone could help me figure it out, it'd be very appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that `conn.get_open_orders` should be `conn.get_open_orders()` (you need to *call* the method).

Comment: In future, anytime you see the words "method" or "function" where you don't expect to in error messages usually means that you aren't calling them or are calling them incorrectly.

Comment: You were right, thank you